# How to sample according to a long array of probabilities of being True in R?

Tags: r, random, vectorization, probability

```
N <- 1000
arr_p_True <- runif(N)
arr_simulated <- sapply(arr_p_True, function(p) {
  sample(c(T, F), 1, prob = c(p, 1 - p))
})
```

`arr_p_True` is what I want to get, but with very large N this is very inefficient. `sample()` does not seem to be the right function to consider in this case, because it is vectorized over the probability of choosing each of the elements in `x`, but not vectorized over the probability of choosing the first element in `x` as required in my example.

I cannot find the right keyword for the purpose... I keep on being directed back to `sample()`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a vector of random numbers from the unit interval. With probability `p` the value will be smaler than `p`:

```
N <- 1000
arr_p_True <- runif(N)
arr_simulated <- runif(N) < arr_p_True
```

Comment: Elegant. Simple yet highly intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do

```
arr_p_True <- runif(N)
as.logical(rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = arr_p_True))
```

But if `arr_p_True` is `runif(N)` in your real code, then this is equivalent to

```
as.logical(rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = 0.5))
```